# Словить событие зажатого button

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Как сделать чтоб когда пользователь нажал на виртуальную клавишу (бутон) и удерживал её 3 секунды , запустить потом функцию, к примеру алерт ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно в момент нажатия ставить таймер на три секунды, спустя которые, будет отображаться алерт. Если пользователь за это время отпустил кнопку - сбрасывать таймер.

Пример:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sftqcxsr/)

```
var timeout_id;

$("#myBtn").on("mousedown", function() {
    timeout_id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert(123);
    }, 3*1000)
});

$("#myBtn").on("mouseup", function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout_id);
});
```